# git update-git-for-windows permission denied

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, administrator

Git 2.41.0 got released 10 days ago and I am updating it via command line on Windows:

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

When the installer is downloaded and invoked, the installer says it has no permission to write to `C:\Program Files\Git\dev`. Obviously that's expected because I never got an administrator prompt. But when I abort the install, it removed all Git executables from there.

I reinstalled Git by downloading the installer, invoking it, same results as above. I shift right-clicked the installer and ran as administrator. Install went as usual.

Few questions:

1. Am I the only one having this "bug"?
2. Is there a tracker for this issue?
3. Why can the installer remove everything in Git, but not making the `dev` folder?

I am running Windows 11 Home, if that's helpful.

Comment: For what it's worth, I always install Git for Windows just for the current user, and so no, I've never had this problem. If you installed it for all users, you'll need to update it as admin, not as a regular user.

Comment: Did you try starting cmd with administrator permissions and then using `git update-git-for-windows`?